# How does a daylight sensor work on minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm inside my house and I have no windows, only torches. Does a daylight sensor tell you if its light outside if it is placed inside?

Comment: This is rather trivially found on the [Minecraft wiki](http://minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Daylight_Sensor).  We don't mind helping users, but we do expect you to try to help yourself before asking here.

Comment: @Frank You are correct, but I highly recommend the [official Minecraft](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Daylight_Sensor) wiki as opposed to the [minecraft.wikia](http://minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Daylight_Sensor) one.

Comment: I have edited the post to make it better. @craftern3rdgurl If this is not what you mean feel free to roll-back my edit.

Answer (score 3):

No, daylight sensors will not detect light inside a house, in fact, they don't detect just any light, they only detect *daylight*. This means you cant place a bunch of torches around the sensor and expect it to output a signal.

Quote from the "[Daylight Sensor](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Daylight_Sensor)" page on the wiki:

> If a daylight sensor has an opaque block above it (such as the roof of your house), then it will emit a weaker signal, or none at all, as it is directly proportional to the sky light.

If you place a daylight sensor in your house, it wont output a redstone signal, this is assuming you have a roof on your house.

One way to have a working daylight sensor in your house is to make a part of your roof glass, and put the sensor underneath it, otherwise known as a skylight. This will work because glass is (obviously) not an opaque block.